# big int from gmp is not working properly with Reduce(accumulate) in R

Tags: r, gmp

I was working with `gmp` library in R, I stumbled upon the below issue, somehow the accumulate function is unable to process for class bigz. It's giving strange result. I have attached the reprex for the same. **Please can some one suggest what is happening here and how can I fix this**. The bigger problem is this, I have file with numbers as text(the numbers are very big), I need some computation on them as R drops precision for large numbers(for example: `900719925474099212` changes to `900719925474099200`) , hence using `gmp` for this. If not `gmp`, then **what are the choices I have?** Thanks for looking into it. I will remove this post if its duplicate but I have searched couldn't find this issue elsewhere. Please let me know if I am doing something silly here.

```r
library(gmp)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'gmp'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     %*%, apply, crossprod, matrix, tcrossprod
library(purrr)

x <- c(9, 16, 7, 178)
Reduce(`*`, x, accumulate = TRUE)
#> [1]      9    144   1008 179424
accumulate(x, `*`)
#> [1]      9    144   1008 179424
x_big <- as.bigz(x)
class(x_big) ## bigz
#> [1] "bigz"
print(x_big)
#> Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 4:
#> [1] 9   16  7   178
Reduce(`*`, x_big, accumulate = FALSE)
#> Big Integer ('bigz') :
#> [1] 179424
Reduce(`*`, x_big, accumulate = TRUE) ## doesn't work correctly
#>  [1] 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01
#> [26] 00 00 00 90 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 f0 03 00 00 01 00
#> [51] 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 e0 bc 02 00
accumulate(x_big, `*`) ## doesn't work correctly
#>  [1] 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01
#> [26] 00 00 00 90 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 f0 03 00 00 01 00
#> [51] 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 e0 bc 02 00
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It is a little more subtle than `Reduce` not working. The part failing is `unlist(as.list(x_big))`, which throws a call to an internal function. So the problem is more 'low-level' and likely stems from `bigz` being stored as a `raw` vectors in the eyes of `R`. So the "fix" is to use methods provided by the `gmp` to perform your calculations.